# converting decimal to long in VB

Tags: vb.net, decimal, long-integer

So when I try running this piece of code, why is it that I get 2 printed.  Does each Decimal get converted to a long and then summed (1 + 1 which is 2) or is the whole Decimal summed first and then rounded (2.5 which should be 3). The weird thing is when I changed the value of x to 1.26, the value printed is 3. 2.51 should round to 3 of course, but with that logic, shouldn't 2.5 also round up?

```
Module VBModule

Sub Main()
    Dim x As Decimal = 1.25
    Dim y As Decimal = 1.25
    Dim z As Long = (x+y)
    Console.WriteLine(z)
End Sub

End Module
```

Thanks!

Comment: Turn option strict on, it will show your implicit conversions

Comment: could you explain what that means?

Comment: By default, fractions of **exactly** 0.5 are rounded to the nearest **even** integer. This is known as Bankers Rounding. As @Cal-cium points out, you should turn `Option Strict On` (for example by making that the first statement in you code file) to prevent unexpected conversions being done.

Comment: [It's written in the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842(v=vs.84).aspx).  "When the fractional part of a value is exactly 0.5, the CLng function rounds to the closest even number."

Comment: It's good practice to have Option Strict On, as @Blackwood said you would save yourself from unexpected conversions happening and that could make it harder to debug your program

Comment: does each Decimal get converted first and then summed? Or is the whole thing summed first and then converted?

Comment: i don't think in the end it makes a difference? maybe i am wrong

Comment: I would assume it adds it together then convert but I may be wrong

Comment: @YusufJama that's why they suggested option strict on. That way you decide when the conversion is done.

Comment: No, the decimals are not converted to integers before being added (otherwise, the result would still be 2 when you make `x` and `y` equal to 1.26. The answer (as I pointed out earlier) is that 2.5 rounds to 2 and not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that fractions ending in 0.5 will be rounded up is incorrect. They are rounded to the nearest **even** integer (so 2.5 rounds to 2, but 3.5 rounds to 4). This is known as [Bankers Rounding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BankersRounding). You can force 0.5 to be rounded up by using the [MidpointRounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx) option with [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Note that using `Math.Round` on a `Decimal` type returns a `Decimal`, so you still need to convert it to a `Long`.

The following code will compile with `Option Strict On` and will display "3" on the console.

```
Dim x As Decimal = 1.25D
Dim y As Decimal = 1.25D
Dim z As Long = CLng(Math.Round(x + y, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
Console.WriteLine(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran the below as a test. z comes out 3 and J comes out 2. So `Dim z As Long = CLng(x + y)` seems to have added the two together then converted. whereas if you convert them seperately and add them you get a different result

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim x As Decimal = CDec(1.26)
    Dim y As Decimal = CDec(1.25)
    Dim z As Long = CLng(x + y)

    Dim F As Long = CLng(x)
    Dim G As Long = CLng(y)
    Dim J As Long = F + G
    Console.WriteLine(z)
    Console.WriteLine(J)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```